# Grails domain class initialization

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, grails-orm, dynamic-finders

My Grails app has the following Spring bean defined in `spring/resources.groovy`

```
calendarService(CalendarService) { bean ->
    bean.initMethod = "init"     
}
```

This method looks something like:

```
class CalendarService {
    void init() {
        User.findByEmail("foo@doo.com")
    }   
}
```

When I call the dynamic finder `findByEmail` I get a `MissingMethodException`. My guess is that I'm trying to call this method too early, i.e. before the domain classes have had the dynamic finders added to their metaclass. One solution would be to call `CalendarService.init()` myself from `Bootstrap.init`, rather than instructing Spring to call it, but is there a better solution?

Thanks,
Don

Answer (score 3):

You're right, as described in this [post](http://www.comitservices.com/wp/?p=89), if you need the dynamic methods you'd better go with BootStrap.groovy

```
BootStrap {
    def calendarService
    def init() {
        calendarService.init()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works without any config in `resources.groovy`

```
class CalendarService {

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        User.findByEmail("foo@doo.com")
    }   
}
```